# Flexbox layout and images height resize

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

Hi i am having a flexbox layout in which I have a header,content and a footer. Everything works fine, except the scaling of the image.
I want that the image scales also in height of content, but for any reason the footer is overlapping it.

This is how it looks like:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
}

.projectHeadline,
.projectFooter {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.swiper-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  height
  background: black;
}

.swiper-wrapper img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="projectHeadline">Headline</div>
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x450">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projectFooter">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having an overflow. You can correct it like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
}

.projectHeadline,
.projectFooter {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.swiper-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  height:100%; /*Added this*/
  background: black;
}

.swiper-wrapper img {
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
  max-height:100%; /*added this*/
  max-width:100%; /*added this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="projectHeadline">Headline</div>
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x450">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projectFooter">Footer</div>
</div>
```